# Can't understand how to find a limit $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find when $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ is differentiable and find the derivative.

I found that it's differentiable when $x \neq 0$ and $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} \ for \ x>0$ and $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{-x}} \ for \ x<0$.

The problem is when checking the limits in 0. It is very clear to me that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\infty$, but when I want to find the limit as x goes to $0^-$, I get the expression $lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{\sqrt{-x}}{x}$ which is going to $-\infty$, but I don't know how to show it.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: That the derivative from the right at $x=0$ doesn't exist is enough to show that the derivative at $x=0$ doesn't exist (note $\sqrt x /x=1/\sqrt x$ for $x\ne0$).

Comment: How can you wite $\sqrt{-x}$

Comment: user2369284, you can write $\sqrt{-x}$ when x<0 - it is not the problem. David - Thank you, understood. Still, I want to understand how to find the limit in $0^-$.

Comment: Notice however that a function might be differentiable in a point even if the limit of the derivative does not exist.

Comment: @Galc127 What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: @Galc127 how did you find that it's differentiable ? And that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} \ for \ x>0$ did you use an elementary derivative or show from definition of derivative ?

Comment: @GinKin just separate it to cases - one for x>0 and one for x<0. Then you only need to check the problematic point x=0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By replacing $x$ with $-x$, we have

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\sqrt{-x}}{x} &= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{-x} \\
&= - \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} \\
&= -\infty
\end{align*}

based on the computation you've already done.

Comment: Your answer seems to be very useful. Unfortunately, I don't understand your first step - How can I make the replacement of x and why $x \rightarrow 0^-$ changed to $x \rightarrow 0^+$?

Comment: @Galc127 If $x$ approaches $0$ from the left, then $-x$ approaches $0$ from the right.

Comment: I understand that, but you didn't write -x, you wrote x and that's what confuses me.

Comment: @Galc127 Set $t = -x$ instead, and rewrite the other steps.

Comment: Isn't this division by zero ? Also, why does it go to minus infinity ?

Comment: @GinKin you can check L'Hospital's rule.
When you have $lim \frac{f}{g}$ and get an inderterminate form of type "$ \frac{[0]}{[0]}$", the limit can be computed as $ \frac{f'}{g'}$